# representing group of symmetries of a triangle in different ways

Tags: abstract-algebra

Here is an exercise from [Birkhoff and MacLane, *A Survey of Modern Algebra*]:

> Represent the group of symmetries of the equilateral triangle as a group of permutations of (a) three and (b) six letters. (c) Do (b) in two essentially different ways.

My question is on part (c).  For (a), we can let the group $G$ of symmetries of an equilateral triangle act on the vertices of the triangle, and this represents $G$ as the symmetric group $S_3$ on three letters.  For (b), we can let $G$ act on the set of three vertices and three edges; the image of this action is an embedding of $S_3$ in $S_6$. We could also take as the six points the three vertices and the midpoints of the three edges.  Regardless of how we choose these six letters, if the goal is to represent $G$ as a subgroup of $S_6$, then it seems that the embedding in $S_6$ must be isomorphic to $S_3$, so I'm not sure what is meant in the exercise by "two essentially different ways". Is there some notion of when two embeddings of $S_3$ in $S_6$ can be considered different?

Answer (score 2):

There are several different notions of "different" that might apply.  If I were assigning this to students then the notion I would choose is that "essentially different" means you didn't just relabel the vertices/edges to get a different embedding.  This translates into saying that you're looking for two different subgroups that are isomorphic to $S_3$ but which are *not* conjugate.

Comment: Conjugate, that's a good one.  So we could pick the six letters to be the three vertices $a,b,c$ and the three midpoints $ab,bc,ac$ of the edges, to get one embedding of $S_3$ into $S_6$.  Or we could pick the six letters to be the three vertices $a,b,c$ along with two midpoints $ab,bc$ and an edge $\{a,b\}$.  Since the latter permutation group acts on both the midpoint $ab$ and the edge $\{a,b\}$, it can't be obtained by just relabeling the points of the former embedding.

Comment: Or even easier, you could get a subgroup of $S_6$ by acting on the three vertices and fixing the other three points.

Comment: For this subgroup of $S_6$ (that acts on the three vertices and fixes the other three points) to arise naturally, I would like for the three fixed points to represent some aspect of the geometric figure.  Perhaps we can take those three points to be the centroid, incenter and circumcenter of the triangle (all three of these coincide in this case) and are fixed by the group of symmetries of the triangle.